# The argument type 'Products Function(BuildContext, dynamic, dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Products Function(BuildContext)'

Tags: flutter, typeerror, non-nullable

I am a new learner following a Flutter tutorial that is written in previous version and I get the following errors with this code:

main.ts:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: Auth(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Products>(
          create: (ctx, auth, previousProducts) => Products(
            auth.token,
            auth.userId,
            previousProducts == null ? [] : previousProducts.items,
          ),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: Cart(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Orders>(
          create: (ctx, auth, previousOrders) => Orders(
            auth.token,
            auth.userId,
            previousOrders == null ? [] : previousOrders.orders,
          ),
        ),
      ],
      child: Consumer<Auth>(
        builder: (ctx, auth, _) => MaterialApp(
          title: 'MyShop',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
            textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
              selectionColor: Colors.deepOrange,
              selectionHandleColor: Colors.blue,
            ),
            fontFamily: 'Lato',
            pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(
              builders: {
                TargetPlatform.android: CustomPageTransitionBuilder(),
                TargetPlatform.iOS: CustomPageTransitionBuilder(),
              },
            ),
          ),
          home: auth.isAuth
              ? ProductsOverviewScreen()
              : FutureBuilder(
                  future: auth.tryAutoLogin(),
                  builder: (ctx, authResultSnapshot) =>
                      authResultSnapshot.connectionState ==
                              ConnectionState.waiting
                          ? SplashScreen()
                          : AuthScreen(),
                ),
          routes: {
            ProductDetailScreen.routeName: (ctx) => ProductDetailScreen(),
            CartScreen.routeName: (ctx) => CartScreen(),
            OrdersScreen.routeName: (ctx) => OrdersScreen(),
            UserProductsScreen.routeName: (ctx) => UserProductsScreen(),
            EditProductScreen.routeName: (ctx) => EditProductScreen(),
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> The named parameter 'update' is required, but there's no corresponding
> argument. Try adding the required argument.
>
> The argument type 'Products Function(BuildContext, dynamic, dynamic)'
> can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Products
> Function(BuildContext)'.

All the errors come from this part of the code( and the other similar part):

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Products>(
  create: (ctx, auth, previousProducts) => Products(
    auth.token,
    auth.userId,
    previousProducts == null ? [] : previousProducts.items,
  ),
```

And this is the Products.ts:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import '../models/http_exception.dart';
import './product.dart';

class Products with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Product> _items = [];
  final String authToken;
  final String userId;

  Products(this.authToken, this.userId, this._items);

  List<Product> get items {
    // if (_showFavoritesOnly) {
    //   return _items.where((prodItem) => prodItem.isFavorite).toList();
    // }
    return [..._items];
  }

  List<Product> get favoriteItems {
    return _items.where((prodItem) => prodItem.isFavorite).toList();
  }

  Product findById(String id) {
    return _items.firstWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
  }


  Future<void> fetchAndSetProducts([bool filterByUser = false]) async {
    final filterString =
        filterByUser ? 'orderBy="creatorId"&equalTo="$userId"' : '';
    var url = Uri.parse(
        'https://flutter-update.firebaseio.com/products.json?auth=$authToken&$filterString');
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      if (extractedData == null) {
        return;
      }
      url = Uri.parse(
          'https://flutter-update.firebaseio.com/userFavorites/$userId.json?auth=$authToken');
      final favoriteResponse = await http.get(url);
      final favoriteData = json.decode(favoriteResponse.body);
      final List<Product> loadedProducts = [];
      extractedData.forEach((prodId, prodData) {
        loadedProducts.add(Product(
          id: prodId,
          title: prodData['title'],
          description: prodData['description'],
          price: prodData['price'],
          isFavorite:
              favoriteData == null ? false : favoriteData[prodId] ?? false,
          imageUrl: prodData['imageUrl'],
        ));
      });
      _items = loadedProducts;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw (error);
    }
  }

  Future<void> addProduct(Product product) async {
    final url = Uri.parse(
        'https://flutter-update.firebaseio.com/products.json?auth=$authToken');
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        url,
        body: json.encode({
          'title': product.title,
          'description': product.description,
          'imageUrl': product.imageUrl,
          'price': product.price,
          'creatorId': userId,
        }),
      );
      final newProduct = Product(
        title: product.title,
        description: product.description,
        price: product.price,
        imageUrl: product.imageUrl,
        id: json.decode(response.body)['name'],
      );
      _items.add(newProduct);
      // _items.insert(0, newProduct); // at the start of the list
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      throw error;
    }
  }

  Future<void> updateProduct(String id, Product newProduct) async {
    final prodIndex = _items.indexWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
    if (prodIndex >= 0) {
      final url = Uri.parse(
          'https://flutter-update.firebaseio.com/products/$id.json?auth=$authToken');
      await http.patch(url,
          body: json.encode({
            'title': newProduct.title,
            'description': newProduct.description,
            'imageUrl': newProduct.imageUrl,
            'price': newProduct.price
          }));
      _items[prodIndex] = newProduct;
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      print('...');
    }
  }

  Future<void> deleteProduct(String id) async {
    final url = Uri.parse(
        'https://flutter-update.firebaseio.com/products/$id.json?auth=$authToken');
    final existingProductIndex = _items.indexWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
    Product? existingProduct = _items[existingProductIndex];
    _items.removeAt(existingProductIndex);
    notifyListeners();
    final response = await http.delete(url);
    if (response.statusCode >= 400) {
      _items.insert(existingProductIndex, existingProduct);
      notifyListeners();
      throw HttpException('Could not delete product.');
    }
    existingProduct = null;
  }
}
```

I don't know what is the problem and how should I solve these errors? I can't find a required parameter named `update` in the `Products` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you are following Maximillian's udemy course. You are using ChangeNotifierProxy because your Products provider is dependent on Auth provider's variables.

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<MyModel, MyChangeNotifier>(
create: (_) => MyChangeNotifier(),
update: (_, myModel, myNotifier) => myNotifier
..update(myModel),
child: ...
);
```

This is how to define a ChangeNotifierProxyProvider.
In your case, it will be:

> without null safety migration

```
         ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Products>(
         create: null,
         update: (context, auth, previousProducts) => Products(auth.token,
         previousProducts == null ? [] : previousProducts.items, 
         auth.userId)),
```

> with null safety migration

```
         ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Products>(
         create: (ctx) => Products('', '', []),
         update: (context, auth, previousProducts) => 
         Products(auth.token,previousProducts.items,auth.userId)),
```

Still if you see any error related to update then you need to upgrade your packages.

Let me know if you further need help :)

Comment: Thank you Sharib, Yes I am using that tutorial course and did what you suggested in code, but it didn't solve my problem and still I get this error message:  `The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Products Function(BuildContext)'.` For this line of code `create: null,`

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Please see the updated answer. @ensan3kamel

Comment: No problem! I could solve the problem like I wrote as a new answer, but I am still interested to know if there is any difference between what I did and what you suggested. Is there any difference either between initializing the variables with empty variables(like what you suggested) or assigning `null` values to them( like what I did)?

Comment: What you did is unnecessary because your project is by default null safety migrated and type cast is also not required. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider` to create a new object. This is a provider which depends on other objects as well to update it's value. Use just the `Provider` by following way:

```
Provider(
  create: (_) => MyModel(),
  child: ...
)
```

This should be enough for your use case.

Comment: I want to pass data of one provider to another provider . so I have used ChangeNotifierProxyProvider .

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could solve my problem by this modification of code:

```
providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: Auth(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Products>(
          create: (ctx) =>
              Products(null as String, null as String, null as List<Product>),
          update: (ctx, auth, previousProducts) => Products(
            auth.token as String,
            auth.userId as String,
            previousProducts == null ? [] : previousProducts.items,
          ),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: Cart(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Orders>(
          create: (ctx) =>
              Orders(null as String, null as String, null as  List<OrderItem>),
          update: (ctx, auth, previousOrders) => Orders(
            auth.token as String,
            auth.userId as String,
            previousOrders == null ? [] : previousOrders.orders,
          ),
        ),
      ],
```